# processing ajax return variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a post request to process some form and send an email.

My code looks like that:

```
$.post(url, data, function(r) {

processFormSubmitResult(r);

}, 'json');

function processFormSubmitResult(r) {
    console.log('text');
    console.log(r);

    if(r !== 'undefined') {
        $('#mistakesModal .modal-body ul.errors').empty();
        $.each(r, function(n, val) {

            if(n != 'email'){
                $('#mistakesModal .modal-body ul.errors').append('<li>השדה <span class="highlight">'+ translateFormToHebrew(n) +'</span> הינו שדה חובה</li>');
            } else {
                $('#mistakesModal .modal-body ul.errors').append('<li>'+ translateFormToHebrew(n) +' אינה תקנית</li>');
            }
        });

        $('#mistakesModal').modal('show');

    }
}
```

When I try to `console.log(r)` it simply doesn't work.. it doesn't even `console.log('text')` but it is indeed processing the errors.. Why is that? I simply want to check if my process page didn't return anything (in that case I expect r to be something else which I'm trying to detect what it would be by conlose.log it)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Errors in the JavaScript console? Network console?  The `$.post` method doesn't have an error handler callback, so you'll have to look at things by hand.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the jQuery ".post" method documentation.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: not sure what you are trying to say. Anyways, I found a workaround by adding another field to my json return variable and check if it exists using the `hasOwnProperty()` function. I just think it's over complicating that issue